# How to set up email alerts for Azure SQL Server database for new sign ups

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

My web app uses ASP.NET MVC and out of box account model for registration. Azure SQL Server table where new sign-ups are stored is `AspNetUsers`.

How can I setup email alerts when a new user signs up on my web site?

Thanks.

Comment: Solved based on Alverto's solution. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782922/how-to-configure-mail-on-azure-sql-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-what-are-logic-apps) to poll the table on the database periodically and add an action item to send an email as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-a-logic-app) or make a RESTful call.

Comment: Used logic App to set a new item SQL trigger and added an action to  send email. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome!