# How to configure mail on Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-sql-server

We are moving from Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
to 
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Previously we send mail from database mail if a particular table have not updated in a particular time interval.

But i tried to do the same on Azure mail but seems like this functionality is not available on this.

Comment: Correct, sending email is not a feature of Azure SQL. You would need to run SQL as IaaS or write some integration with sendgrid (https://sendgrid.com/partners/azure/) in order to mail out. Logic apps may give you a good framework to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Stored Procedure to query the table and return results, read the results in an Azure WebJob, Logic App or Azure Function, schedule the execution and send the results via email. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1226872/Send-Email-from-Azure-SQL-using-Logic-App) you can find an example using a Logic App and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/schedule-logic-apps-to-run-in-the-future/) you can find how to schedule it.

You can use your own Exchange/SMTP server or you can choose to use SendGrid to send out the email as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email).

Comment: I don't see how any of these examples show how to email the results of a query through SendGrid.  The first example just sends a notification email to the admin or whoever created the logic app.  The second just schedules it, and the third shows how to send email via SendGrid in C#.